# Bluetooth Profile Tuning Suite : PTS dongle must be connected to create new workspace

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-profile

I will open Bluetooth Profile Tuning Suite (PTS) program to test my Bluetooth device in windows 7 (64).

When I try to start New Workspace (FILE -> New Workspace). It always popup dialog box and prompt that “*PTS dongle must be connected to create new workspace*”

I am not understand what mean of this dialog. How to I do to start new workspace. and I do not know which step went wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to purchase a PTS dongle from the SIG website (link https://bluetoothstore.org/)

When you get it, follow this wiki to install the driver correctly [wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/QA/Bluetooth_PTS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/QA/Bluetooth_PTS)

The next time you will start the PTS software it will detect the dongle.

Comment: Thank you for update information. I found it need retry the Driver installation   for PTS dongle step. and restart PTS program . It's work~